# difference between string.empty and isNullOrEmpty?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have the following short piece of code that is never returning the string "selected".

```
Protected Function SelectedType(ByVal val As String) As String
    If val <> String.Empty Then Return "selected"
End Function
```

However, if I change it to this, it works.  Is there anything wrong when my shorthand code above? -Thanks

```
Protected Function SelectedType(ByVal val As String) As String
    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(val) Then
        Return "selected"
    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`String.Empty` is `""`, null is `Nothing`.

you can compare if a string is null, if it's empty, or both at the same time with `IsNullOrEmpty ()`

Comment: so: If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(val) Then Return "selected"?

Comment: btw I'm trying to keep it on a single line

Comment: yes, that's correct. `val` is probably `Nothing` that's why the first code never returns "selected"

Answer (score 3):

When you call `If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(val) Then`, you're checking to see if the value is equal to `String.Empty` or if the value is equal to `Nothing`.

This would be more like writing your first example as:

```
Protected Function SelectedType(ByVal val As String) As String
    If val <> Nothing And val <> String.Empty Then 
        Return "selected"
    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

IsNullOrEmpty offers additional security against null values, where otherwise your code would fail